# Kafka duplicates some messages hundreds of times

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using 3 Kafka brokers in a cluster using Kafka 2.3.0. Then I have a streaming application that consumes data from an other kafka cluster which transforms data and pushes this data to the before mentioned 3 kafka broker cluster.

The streaming application has a producer written in Java using Spring Cloud Stream Greenwhich.SR1. This producer uses the following code to push messages:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Slf4j
@Component
@EnableBinding(SensorDataBinding.class)
public class SensorDataProducer {

    private final SensorDataBinding sensorDataOut;
    private final long sendTimeoutInMilliseconds;

    public SensorDataProducer(SensorDataBinding binding,
                              @Value("${sendTimeoutInMilliseconds}") long sendTimeoutInMilliseconds) {
        this.sensorDataOut = binding;
        this.sendTimeoutInMilliseconds = sendTimeoutInMilliseconds;
    }

    public void produce(SensorData sensorMeasurement) {
        send(sensorMeasurement);
    }

    private void send(SensorData sensorMeasurement) {
        log.trace("sending message with contents: {}", sensorMeasurement.toString());
        Message<SensorData> message = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(sensorMeasurement)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, getMessageKey(sensorMeasurement))
                .build();

        failSafeMessageSend(message);
    }

    private void failSafeMessageSend(Message<SensorData> message) {
        boolean sendSucceeded = false;
        do {
            try {
                this.sensorDataOut.sensorDataOut().send(message, this.sendTimeoutInMilliseconds);
                sendSucceeded = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Exception when sending message: {}", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        while (!sendSucceeded);
    }

    private byte[] getMessageKey(SensorData measurement) {
        return (measurement.getMessageKey()).getBytes();
    }
}
```

Producer config:

```
ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9095]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [https://....:...]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = client-1ae836b8-9a13-4903-aad6-09ce11a4be08-StreamThread-1-producer
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 100
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 10
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = keystore/prod/client.keystore.p12
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = PKCS12
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = keystore/prod/client.truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

on our environment we have 8 instances of this application that are part of a consumer group which are consuming from a topic of 60 partitions on the external cluster. As mentioned this data is transformed and pushed on our own 3 broker Kafka cluster setup. The data is pushed to a sensor-data-topic which has 30 partitions, a retention time of 7 days and delete compaction.

I'm fully aware of duplicate messages using at least once semantics, but I'm seeing some messages being duplicated sometimes over 300 times, causing the required disksize to grow tremendously, while other messages are duplicated max 3 or 4.

The following is an example of some metrics that shows a message being duplicated 233 times where the timestamps array shows the timestamp of each message and the offsets array shows the offset of each message that is seen as duplicate:

```
Key: b'100083952:300793850'|-|1591011300000. Value: {'count': 233, 'partition': 3, 'offset': 26637463, 'timestamps': [1594133472060, 1594133472062, 1594133472064, 1594133472066, 1594133472068, 1594133472071, 1594133472072, 1594133472074, 1594133472076, 1594133472081, 1594133472084, 1594133472085, 1594133472087, 1594133472090, 1594133472092, 1594133472095, 1594133472097, 1594133472099, 1594133472102, 1594133472103, 1594133472105, 1594133472107, 1594133472111, 1594133472113, 1594133472115, 1594133472117, 1594133472119, 1594133472121, 1594133472139, 1594133472141, 1594133472155, 1594133472157, 1594133472160, 1594133472163, 1594133472166, 1594133472169, 1594133472171, 1594133472174, 1594133472179, 1594133472181, 1594133472188, 1594133472190, 1594133472193, 1594133472195, 1594133472197, 1594133472199, 1594133472201, 1594133472204, 1594133472207, 1594133472209, 1594133472212, 1594133472215, 1594133472217, 1594133472219, 1594133472221, 1594133472222, 1594133472224, 1594133472227, 1594133472229, 1594133472231, 1594133472234, 1594133472235, 1594133472237, 1594133472240, 1594133472242, 1594133472243, 1594133472247, 1594133472249, 1594133472252, 1594133472255, 1594133472257, 1594133472262, 1594133472267, 1594133472270, 1594133472272, 1594133472275, 1594133472277, 1594133472279, 1594133472282, 1594133472289, 1594133472293, 1594133472295, 1594133472297, 1594133472299, 1594133472300, 1594133472303, 1594133472305, 1594133472307, 1594133472309, 1594133472311, 1594133472312, 1594133472316, 1594133472319, 1594133472321, 1594133472323, 1594133472325, 1594133472327, 1594133472333, 1594133472335, 1594133472337, 1594133472338, 1594133472341, 1594133472343, 1594133472346, 1594133472351, 1594133472356, 1594133472359, 1594133472361, 1594133472363, 1594133472364, 1594133472366, 1594133472371, 1594133472374, 1594133472377, 1594133472379, 1594133472381, 1594133472385, 1594133472393, 1594133472399, 1594133472401, 1594133472402, 1594133472404, 1594133472406, 1594133472409, 1594133472412, 1594133472413, 1594133472415, 1594133472417, 1594133472419, 1594133472421, 1594133472423, 1594133472425, 1594133472427, 1594133472429, 1594133472432, 1594133472434, 1594133472436, 1594133472439, 1594133472442, 1594133472469, 1594133472479, 1594133472483, 1594133472485, 1594133472488, 1594133472491, 1594133472494, 1594133472496, 1594133472498, 1594133472500, 1594133472503, 1594133472506, 1594133472508, 1594133472510, 1594133472512, 1594133472515, 1594133472520, 1594133472522, 1594133472524, 1594133472526, 1594133472528, 1594133472530, 1594133472532, 1594133472534, 1594133472535, 1594133472537, 1594133472539, 1594133472541, 1594133472543, 1594133472545, 1594133472547, 1594133472549, 1594133472551, 1594133472552, 1594133472554, 1594133472556, 1594133472558, 1594133472560, 1594133472562, 1594133472564, 1594133472566, 1594133472568, 1594133472570, 1594133472572, 1594133472573, 1594133472575, 1594133472577, 1594133472579, 1594133472581, 1594133472583, 1594133472587, 1594133472589, 1594133472593, 1594133472595, 1594133472596, 1594133472598, 1594133472599, 1594133472601, 1594133472603, 1594133472605, 1594133472606, 1594133472609, 1594133472611, 1594133472613, 1594133472615, 1594133472619, 1594133472622, 1594133472624, 1594133472626, 1594133472631, 1594133472633, 1594133472635, 1594133472637, 1594133472639, 1594133472641, 1594133472643, 1594133472644, 1594133472646, 1594133472649, 1594133472651, 1594133472653, 1594133472654, 1594133472657, 1594133472659, 1594133472660, 1594133472662, 1594133472664, 1594133472666, 1594133472667, 1594133472669, 1594133472671, 1594133472673, 1594133472675, 1594133472676], 
'offsets': 
[26637463, 26637464, 26637465, 26637466, 26637467, 26637468, 26637469, 26637470, 26637471, 26637472, 26637473, 26637474, 26637475, 26637476, 26637477, 26637478, 26637479, 26637480, 26637481, 26637482, 26637483, 26637484, 26637485, 26637486, 26637487, 26637488, 26637489, 26637490, 26637491, 26637492, 26637493, 26637494, 26637495, 26637496, 26637497, 26637498, 26637499, 26637500, 26637501, 26637502, 26637503, 26637504, 26637505, 26637506, 26637507, 26637508, 26637509, 26637510, 26637511, 26637512, 26637513, 26637514, 26637515, 26637516, 26637517, 26637518, 26637519, 26637520, 26637521, 26637522, 26637523, 26637524, 26637525, 26637526, 26637527, 26637528, 26637529, 26637530, 26637531, 26637532, 26637533, 26637534, 26637535, 26637536, 26637537, 26637538, 26637539, 26637540, 26637541, 26637542, 26637543, 26637544, 26637545, 26637546, 26637547, 26637548, 26637549, 26637550, 26637551, 26637552, 26637553, 26637554, 26637555, 26637556, 26637557, 26637558, 26637559, 26637560, 26637561, 26637562, 26637563, 26637564, 26637565, 26637566, 26637567, 26637568, 26637569, 26637570, 26637571, 26637572, 26637573, 26637574, 26637575, 26637576, 26637577, 26637578, 26637579, 26637580, 26637581, 26637582, 26637583, 26637584, 26637585, 26637586, 26637587, 26637588, 26637589, 26637590, 26637591, 26637592, 26637593, 26637594, 26637595, 26637596, 26637597, 26637598, 26637599, 26637600, 26637601, 26637602, 26637603, 26637604, 26637605, 26637606, 26637607, 26637608, 26637609, 26637610, 26637611, 26637612, 26637613, 26637614, 26637615, 26637616, 26637617, 26637618, 26637619, 26637620, 26637621, 26637622, 26637623, 26637624, 26637625, 26637626, 26637627, 26637628, 26637629, 26637630, 26637631, 26637632, 26637633, 26637634, 26637635, 26637636, 26637637, 26637638, 26637639, 26637640, 26637641, 26637642, 26637643, 26637644, 26637645, 26637646, 26637647, 26637648, 26637649, 26637650, 26637651, 26637652, 26637653, 26637654, 26637655, 26637656, 26637657, 26637658, 26637659, 26637660, 26637661, 26637662, 26637663, 26637664, 26637665, 26637666, 26637667, 26637668, 26637669, 26637670, 26637671, 26637672, 26637673, 26637674, 26637675, 26637676, 26637677, 26637678, 26637679, 26637680, 26637681, 26637682, 26637683, 26637684, 26637685, 26637686, 26637687, 26637688, 26637689, 26637690, 26637691, 26637692, 26637693, 26637694, 26637695], 
Date: 2020-06-01 13:35:00
```

You can see the offset monotonically increasing.

I'm wondering what could cause this difference between only a few duplicate messages compared to the many hundred duplicate messages. I'm expecting that the retries property would have a hand in limiting the number of duplicates although it doesn't really show.

Comment: maybe there is some network problem that Kafka broker cannot return ACK to the producer app

Comment: I'm tracing the KafkaTemplate log and noticing only "Sent ok" messages, no "Failed to send" messages seen. Is this how to detect any network failures?

Comment: Did some additional checks of network metrics and there seem to be no packet drops at all during the time that duplicate messages have been created